# Html form select blank to search all of the table where the other fields match

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have a form that searches a database and returns rows that match the fields specified. I want to give an option to the user that if the field is left blank, it won't matter what is is that column as long as the other fields match. Right now, if I leave a field 'blank' it will return every entry in the database.

```
        Hair Color: <select name="hair">
                    <option value="hairall" selected="selected">--</option>
                    <option value="black" >Black</option>
                    <option value="brown">Brown</option>
                    <option value="blonde">Blonde</option>
                    <option value="white">White</option>
                    <option value="red">Red</option>
                    <option value="other">Other</option>

                </select>
        Height: <select name="height">
                    <option value="heightall" selected="selected">--</option>
                    <option value="smaller">Smaller</option>
                    <option value="small">Small</option>
                    <option value="average">Average - 70in</option>
                    <option value="tall">Tall</option>
                    <option value="taller">Taller</option>
                </select>
        Body Type: <select name="body">
                    <option value="bodyall" selected="selected">--</option>
                    <option value="skinny">Skinny</option>
                    <option value="average">Average - 194lb</option>
                    <option value="heavy">Heavy</option>
                </select>
        Ethnicity: <select name="ethnicity">
                    <option value="ethnicityall" selected="selected">--</option>
                    <option value="white">White</option>
                    <option value="black">Black</option>
                    <option value="asian">Asian</option>
                    <option value="hispanic">Hispanic</option>
                    <option value="middleeast">Middle Eastern</option>
                    <option value="other">Other</option>
                    </select><br/>
        <center><input type="submit" value="Find Me" name="submit" ></center>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="results">
    <?php
            $submit = $_GET['submit'];
            $gender = $_GET['gender'];
            $hair = $_GET['hair'];
            $height = $_GET['height'];
            $body = $_GET['body'];
            $race = $_GET['ethnicity'];

            //Hair All/Specific
            if ($hair=='hairall'){
                $newhair = "black' OR `hair`='brown' OR `hair`='blonde' OR `hair`='white' OR `hair`='red' OR `hair`='other";
            }else
                $newhair=$hair;

            //Height All/Specific
            if ($height=='heightall'){
                $newheight = "smaller' OR `height`='small' OR `height`='average' OR `height`='tall' OR `height`='taller";
            }else
                $newheight=$height;

            //Body Type All/specific
            if ($body=='bodyall'){
                $newbody = "skinny' OR `body`='average' OR `body`='heavy";
            }else
                $newbody=$body;

            //Etnicity All/Specific
            if ($race=='ethnicityall'){
                $newrace = "white' OR `race`='black' OR `race`='asian' OR `race`='hispanic' OR `race`='middleeast' OR `race`='other";
            }else
                $newrace=$race;

            //echo "$newhair <br/> $newheight <br/> $newbody <br/> $newrace<br/>";
            require 'connect.inc.php';

            $query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `gender`='$gender' AND `hair`='$newhair' AND `height`='$newheight' AND `body`='$body' AND `race`='$race' ORDER BY `id` DESC";
```

Comment: This is more a PHP question than anything else.  HTML and SQL aren't very well suited to implementing this particular requirement; PHP is.

Comment: This is unrelated to your actual question, but... that code is very vulnerable to SQL injection.  You should probably fix that (see [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)).

Answer (score 0):

Put parenthesis around each of your values - i.e. `('$gender')` instead of `'$gender'`.  That will prevent your OR clauses from messing up your AND clauses, which is the problem you're having.

A better solution would be to remove the check from the query entirely if the field is left blank, but that would require rewriting about half your code.  In any case, here's roughly how I would do it:

```
// Only accept the specific fields that are expected
$query_fields = array_intersect_key($_GET, array(
    'gender'=>true,
    'hair'=>true,
    'height'=>true,
    'body'=>true,
    'ethnicity'=>true,
));

// Exclude blank fields
$query_fields = array_filter($query_fields, 'strlen');

$database = (require 'connect.inc.php'); // Get connection to database in this variable somehow

$where_parts = array();
foreach($query_fields as $k=>$v) {
    $v = $database->real_escape_string($v);
    $where_parts[] = "`$k` = '$v'";
}

if(!$where_parts)
    die('No filters selected!');

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $where_parts).' ORDER BY `id` DESC';
```

Comment: How would I go about doing the second method you mentioned?

Comment: Edited my version of the code into my answer.  A simpler way would be to change `$newheight=$height;` to `$newheight=" AND ``height`` = '$height'";` and, well, change all of the other lines accordingly (the "do not filter" lines would become `$newheight=''`, and that section of the query would become simply `$newheight` - then do the same with each other variable).